# AngularJS loop over multiple arrays in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, loops

Which is the easiest way to loop over this array in JS?

```
[[45,67,4],[7.8,6.8,56],[8,7,8.7]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In html with angular:

```
<!-- assuming myArray is a variable on $scope object -->
<div ng-repeat="innerArray in myArray"> 
    <div ng-repeat="value in innerArray"> 
        {{ value }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Or in js, use `for`-loops:

```js
var myArray = [[45,67,4],[7.8,6.8,56],[8,7,8.7]];
    
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var innerArray = myArray[i];
    // loop through inner array
    for (var j = 0; j < innerArray.length; j++) {
        var myValue = innerArray[j];
        console.log(myValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is three any option in angularJs for not to create extra one div `<div ng-repeat="value in innerArray">` during iteration

Answer (score 1):

By using ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="subArray in masterArray"> 
   <div ng-repeat="element in subArray"> 
       {{element}}
   </div>
</div>
```

will yield as result `45 67 4 7.8 6.8 56 8 7 8.7`

In javascript (angularjs it's not necessary here)

```
masterArray.forEach(function(subArray) {
   subArray.forEach(function(element) {
       console.log(element);
   }); 
});
```